# Get array of properties from an array angular 4

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have an array of tasks in my Angular 4 application which I display in a table. The JSON for this looks like:

```
[
    {
        "id": "353610d2-4a6d-4dc3-9468-b88732d98397",
        "dueDate": "20/12/2017",
        "claimNumber": "19875677",
        "actionType": "Admission",
        "actionName": "Call TP Insurer",
        "owner": "Ben Clarke",
        "tags": [
            {
                "id": "78ef9592-7ed6-4192-aecc-4be8bb561f67",
                "description": "Third Party 2",
                "colour": "#df9626"
            }
        ]       
    }
]
```

I then display this list in a table like so:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date Due</th>
      <th>
        <span (click)="onDisplayContext($event, 'ClaimNumber')">Claim Number</span>
      </th>
      <th>
        <span (click)="onDisplayContext($event, 'ActionType')">Action Type</span>
      </th>
      <th>
        <span (click)="onDisplayContext($event, 'ActionName')">Action Name</span>
      </th>
      <th>
        <span (click)="onDisplayContext($event, 'Owner')">Owner</span>
      </th>
      <th>
        <span (click)="onDisplayContext($event, 'Tags')">Tags</span>
      </th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let task of Tasks; let i = index">
      <td>{{task.dueDate}}</td>
      <td>{{task.claimNumber}}</td>
      <td>{{task.actionType}}</td>
      <td>{{task.actionName}}</td>
      <td>{{task.owner}}</td>
      <td>
        <div fxLayout="row">

          <div *ngFor="let tag of task.tags; let r = index">
            <span class="tag" [style.background-color]="tag.colour">{{tag.description}}</span>
          </div>
        </div>

      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="chk_round">
          <input type="checkbox" id="chk_{{task.id}}" />
          <label for="chk_{{task.id}}"></label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Now as you can see from the HTML each `<th>` is clickable, this should open a popup for which it should display all the distinct values in that column.

I am wondering I have my initial list of tasks, how would I create another array from that array with just the column that was clicked by the user?

Comment: by distinct you mean all the unique values in a column? if thats the case, how do you define a tag as unique? By its id?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo In this case all the tags with different Descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

```
public onDisplayContext($event, columnKey) {
  let colArray = []
  this.Tasks.map(task => {
    colArray.push(task[columnKey]);
  });
  //some code here
}
```

Hope it will help

Comment: why map? you dont use the value returned from the map function

Comment: I dont need to return anything. I just created another array from your Tasks array. You can also use forEach to do the same task.

Comment: If you dont need to return anything from the function applied to the array, then you are using map for a wrong use case. ForEach would be better IMO

Answer (score 0):

Your data model and what you call in the `onDisplayContext` are a bit out of sync, but you can do something like this:

Adjust the prop name to match what's in the actual data:

```
onDisplayContext($event, 'claimNumber')
```

Do this all accross your template, for all your props.

Get the data within your component:

```
onDisplayContext($event, key: string) {
  // filter the unique values
  const uniques= this.Tasks
    .map(row => row[key])   // get the property values
    .filter((val, idx, arr) => arr.indexOf(val) === idx); // find uniques
  this.displayData(uniques);
}
```

Implement the `displayData` method:

```
displayData(data: any[]) {
  // call a popup or whatever here.
  console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: .indexof(value) where does the value property come from?

Comment: Sorry, fixed. Typing on small screens does things to your perception :)